# Cannot convert String[] to string in java using split("\\s")

Tags: java, input, split

I have been trying to input N numbers on a straight line, and since I want to N of these lines I wrote the following code snippet.

```
public static void main (String args []) throws IOException
{
InputStreamReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int N = in.readLine();
String line [];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   line [i] = in.readLine().split("\\s");
}
```

Whenever I type this it shows that it cannot convert from String[] to String.

Comment: use the scanner instead.

Comment: Invest a bit of your time and read [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign an *array* of `String` to a single index of an array, which can only hold an individual `String`. You need to assign the array directly to the variable:

```
line = in.readLine().split("\\s");
// do something with line
```

Alternatively, if you're planning on using the lines after the loop, you can store them in a 2-dimensional array:

```
String[][] lines = new String[N][];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    line[i] = in.readLine().split("\\s");
}
```

Comment: @JIGMELOBSANGLEPCHA don't forgot to accept the answer if that help you can take a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work